# 500 error with javascript redirect on a Joomla site

Tags: javascript, redirect, joomla, joomla1.5

I have a few javascript redirects set up on my Joomla site. If someone goes to woodridgelibrary.org/zinio it redirects them to http://www.woodridgelibrary.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=247&Itemid=104&Itemid=21. It worked just fine up until yesterday. Now all the redirects give a 500 Internal Server Error. I haven't changed any options in the backend and the scripts haven't been touched. I checked to make sure the URLs hadn't changed.

What's weird is that the redirects do work if I use my iPhone and 4G. They don't work on wireless.

The script I'm using is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--// /
var delay = 0; // Delay in seconds
var targetURL = "http://www.woodridgelibrary.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=266&Itemid=26"; // URL to load
setTimeout('self.location.replace(targetURL)', (delay * 1));
//-->
  </script>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15;URL=http://www.woodridgelibrary.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=266&Itemid=26">
  <title>Redirect</title>


</head>

<body>

<p></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

The .htaccess is

```
#RewriteEngine On
########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
#RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
#RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#


##
# @version $Id: htaccess.txt 14401 2010-01-26 14:10:00Z louis $
# @package Joomla
# @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
# Joomla! is Free Software
##


#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
#Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#

## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>

## End of deny access to extension xml files
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /


########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Comment: is there anything in the error log on the server?

Comment: There's nothing on the error log.

Comment: do you have `.htaccess` file? can you post the content of it?

Comment: Just added it to the original post.

Comment: currently your link throws `404` error, meaning there is no page there

Comment: Egads. I hope you'll be migrating that site to 2.5 soon.

Comment: I'd changed a directory name to change something. Should go back to a 500 error now.

Comment: I want nothing more than to upgrade to 2.5 but the template we use isn't compatible and we don't want a new template. So we're stuck with 1.5 for now.

Comment: redirection works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I may offer an alternative solution, I usually create such redirects with hidden menu items.

1. Create a new menu that's *not* published in the site via a module or template.
2. Create an item in that menu with the alias you want, such as 'zinio', and point it at your article.

That's it. No fuss, no muss. Joomla 2.5 also has a redirect component that may do what you want.

Comment: That's pretty genius. It worked for that one page and later I'm going to do that for the others. Thanks so much!

I wish we were using 2.5 but that's a ways off, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new menu that's not published

a better way to do this is to use a module published in a nonexistent position, so you can use the menu parameters.